# How to avoid a mongoid_alize callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, mongoid

I would like to create one contact for each Device. At this moment this two models are independent, but I am creating a one to one dependency. Let's introduce the context:

given a Device model:

```
class Device
   # some ommited code
   belongs_to :contact, autosave: true, index: true
end
```

and given a Contact model which uses alize:

```
class Contact
   # some ommited code
   has_one :device
   alize :device, :app_id, :type
end
```

I created a task that executes bulk inserts into the contact and device models.

```
device = Device.find("xxxxxxa2")
contact = device.contact
device.destroy
```

The problem here is that `device.destroy` is automatically removing the `device_fields` created in the contact document, and I want to maintain this info.

**How can I temporarily avoid this `after/before_destroy` callback?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mongoid_alize` gem automatically creates callback methods in the affected models classes.

`device.destroy` will call a callback in the `Device` model which name is `denormalize_destroy_to_contact`.

My solution was to overwrite this method before calling the task:

```
class Device
  def denormalize_destroy_to_contact
    nil
  end
end

device = Device.find("xxxxxxa2")
contact = device.contact
device.destroy
```